# Can't get JSON properties to display via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, yql

For some reason I just can't seem to be able to display properties from this JSON string:
http://www.easports.com/iframe/fifa14proclubs/api/platforms/PS4/clubs/51694/members

I've sat here for the last 2-3 hours trying out different ways to select single properties such as the name of the first person in the array. A couple selectors I've tried:

```
$("#output").append(data.raw[0].176932931.name);
$("#output").append(data.raw[0][0].name);
```

I always get the same error. "data.raw[0] is undefined". The JSON string is valid, I'm able to output the whole string to my page using:

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=data.toSource();
```

Parsing it into a JSON object gives me another error because it already is a JSON object. By using console.log(data) I'm able to view the JSON object properly in Firebug.

**data** is the name of the Javascript JSON object variable that is being returned from my YQL statement.

Please, if anyone could provide some examples as to how I should go about accessing the properties of the above JSON string, that would be great.

**UPDATE:**

Here's the callback function from my YQL statement:

```
function cbfunc(json)
{ 
   if (json.query.count)
   { 
      var data = json.query.results.json;
      $("#output").append(data.raw[0]["176932931"].name);
   }
```

Comment: did you try console.log the object ?

Comment: Yep, and it displays properly. I'm able to go through each of the objects and view their properties.

Comment: Your json works check this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/q8xL3/

Comment: Check my edit in the main post, I posted the callback function where my 'data' variable is being assigned.

Comment: so what is the question now ?

Comment: It works when I assign the big JSON string straight to the data variable, but when I use "var data = json.query.results.json;" it gives me an error. Odd.

Comment: the object you posted is contained with in what ? is it contained within "json" ?

Comment: The big JSON string from the website is contained in json, yes. When I console.log(json) I get an object representation of it in Firebug. I think it needs to be in a different format to be read into the data variable.

Comment: if its within "json" then json.query.results.json is wrong and should return undefined as this property is not defined. which would also make your if wrong. check my answer tell me if it works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation), as identifiers starting with digits are invalid

```
$("#output").append(data.raw[0]["176932931"].name);
```

Comment: Tried this and it's still giving me "data.raw[0] is undefined". No idea why. :/

Comment: he is saying though that the error is that raw[0] is undefiend therefore ["176932931"] will be undefined as well

Comment: @samer.j92, See it works http://jsfiddle.net/q8Tqu/ I have used data from your URL

Comment: Check my edit in the main post, I posted the callback function where my 'data' variable is being assigned.

Answer (score 1):

as `"176932931"` is an integer key so you have to access like `json["176932931"]`.

For example

```
data.raw[0]["176932931"].name
```

see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mLP4G/)

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if this works for you:

```
function cbfunc(json)
{

    $each(json, function(key, object){
         console.log(key, object);
    });
    var raw = query.results.json.raw;
    console.log(raw );


    // uncomment it if you want some extra check.
    if (/*typeof data.raw !=='undefined' && */data.raw.length > 0)
    { 
        //console.log(data.raw[0]["176932931"].name);
        //$("#output").append(data.raw[0]["176932931"].name);
    }
}
```

If this works for you there's no need to reference the object to data, simply use the object its self.

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q8xL3/2/

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything. Doesn't give me any errors and nothing is displayed on the page.

Comment: Fixed it check the solution again

Comment: That gives me the same error as before: TypeError: data.raw is undefined

Comment: remove all your console.logs, and do a console log of what i did in my answer and send that here

Comment: tell me what you get from the above

Comment: i need more info on json object, if you had join me or some way of showing the object i could assist farther.

Comment: Doesn't help much as i cant see the returned object.

Comment: Here's the entire json object in my Firebug console:
http://i.imgur.com/mvYMYYI.png

Comment: What are you getting if you do the above changes

Comment: The query object is being returned and this error:

ReferenceError: query is not defined

Comment: did the each output all the keys/values ? and did `console.log(raw );` logged the raws ? also your raw keys is not a numeric its a string btw with that _121212

Comment: The each didn't output anything. The console.log(raw) outputted query > results > json > raw in that order.

Comment: Dont know what to tell you. this is weird

Answer (score 0):

.count isn't a property of a json object. Try this:

```
var something = {"raw":[{"176932931":{"name":"Shipdawg","blazeId":176932931,"clubStatus":0,"onlineStatus":0,"nucleusId":2266699357,"personaName":"Shipdawg"},"182141183":{"name":"Beks8","blazeId":182141183,"clubStatus":0,"onlineStatus":0,"nucleusId":2272736228,"personaName":"Beks8"},"219929617":{"name":"ChelseaFC_26","blazeId":219929617,"clubStatus":0,"onlineStatus":0,"nucleusId":2304510098,"personaName":"ChelseaFC_26"},"457588267":{"name":"Lazy__Rich","blazeId":457588267,"clubStatus":0,"onlineStatus":0,"nucleusId":2495578386,"personaName":"Lazy__Rich"},"517570695":{"name":"x0__andrew__0x","blazeId":517570695,"clubStatus":0,"onlineStatus":1,"nucleusId":2549150176,"personaName":"x0__andrew__0x"},"912396727":{"name":"mizz00-","blazeId":912396727,"clubStatus":0,"onlineStatus":1,"nucleusId":1000118566560,"personaName":"mizz00-"},"915144354":{"name":"MisterKanii","blazeId":915144354,"clubStatus":2,"onlineStatus":0,"nucleusId":2281969661,"personaName":"MisterKanii"}}]}


function cbfunc(json)
{ 
   if (json.raw.length)
   { 
      $("#output").append(json.raw["0"]["176932931"].name);
   }
}

cbfunc(something);
```